# Hybris : Addons is not working(overriding)

Tags: spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I am new to Hybris environment. For past two days i have been working on addons concept. i can able to copy my addon files to the target storefront successfully and also compiled with no error. But the issue is my addon is not working(overriding) the functionality of the core code base. The core code is only executing.

I tried to debug, debugger is entering into my corresponding addon controller, then i got the following error message from eclipse. then it jumps into the core code controller and it got executed.

Can someone explain me the complete workflow of the AddOn and also the mistake that i have committed?
[image: image description here] Any sort of answer is welcome from the Hybris developers. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you add your extension to localextensions.xml?

Comment: Yeah. i have added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have committed mistake in  < storefrontTemplateName >. The command to install addon is

```
ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="addon_name" -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront="custom_storefront_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have done some 'copy and paste action' or did you use the install command from hybris? You have to explicit 'install' the addon. Have a look here how it is working:

https://wiki.hybris.com/display/accdoc50to56/Installing+an+AddOn+for+a+Specific+Storefront